# Inspect page not working when trying to run the code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, console, web-inspector

Recently when I try to open the inspect page from Vscode for the output for the JavaScript code the console page starts to freeze and it begins using up too much memory like up to 4gb. It even takes time to close the tab cause my laptop begins to freeze and it becomes really hot after that I don't know why.
I thought it was some problem with the browser so i changed to to Microsoft edge and I get the same problem and I even tried to reinstall both Vscode and chrome but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error occurs if our code make repetitive call and call stack goes in deadlock condition.  Just try running new simple application you can find that error will not occur.

Try to find out which piece of code making that call again and again

In chrome developer tool you can see call stack also for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah you were right there was one function which was making repetitive calls and that made the console page lag a lot.